# Images not generating fast enough, no image data sent

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, imageresizer

This is probably a performance issue, but I'm wondering how I'd go about proving that.

I set up an Image Resizer website and it works fine if I'm clicking on links to images, but if I use the following code to display a bunch of pictures on a website, the images do not show.

I'm wondering if it's because ImageResizer is being called so many times so quickly (only 15x) and it's getting tripped up somehow. I know enough to implement this and be dangerous, but not enough to understand what the hangup is here. It's possible that Dynamics CRM 2013 (what this code is being run as part of) has some code timeout or something that just skips showing the images if they take too long to load... not sure on that end.

Any and all help would be appreciated! Thanks everyone!

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Image View</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function getImages() {
var unitSerial = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_serial").getValue();
var guid = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
guid = guid.substring(1, guid.length-1);
var imageHTML = "<table><tr>";
for (var i=1; i<16; i++) {
imageURL = "http://website/Images/" + guid + "-" + unitSerial + "-" + i + ".png";
imageHTML = imageHTML + "<td><a href='"+imageURL+"' target=_blank><img height=95px border=0px width=130px source='"+imageURL+"?maxwidth=130&maxheight=95' /><br /><center>Pic " + i +"</center></a></td>";
            } 
imageHTML = imageHTML + "</tr></table>";
document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = imageHTML;
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="images"></div><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">getImages();</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Inspect the DOM using Developer Tools in your browser of choice. Provide us the HTML that corresponds to the DOM, and also the response you get if you visit an image directly. You're many steps away from ImageResizer here.

Comment: Hi Nathanael thanks for taking the time to reply! Sorry I guess I could have included that info. When I right click where the image is supposed to be and Inspect Element, it shows properly, and if I click on the img src, it loads fine in new window.



`<td><a href="http://images.website.com/Images/03BA7D61-6C81-E411-9C52-005056AEE120-1HTJSSKK0GH002094-1.png" target="_blank"><img width="130" height="95" border="0" source="http://images.website.com/Images/03BA7D61-6C81-E411-9C52-005056AEE120-1HTJSSKK0GH002094-1.png?maxwidth=130&amp;maxheight=95&amp;speed=2"><br><center>Pic 1</center></a></td>`

Comment: We want to know the response if you open the image (not the link) in a new tab. What happens when you put `http://images.website.com/Images/03BA7D61-6C81-E411-9C52-005056AEE120-1H‌​TJSSKK0GH002094-1.png?maxwidth=130&maxheight=95&speed=2` directly into your address bar?

Comment: Oh sorry yes the image generates just fine. Always missing some detail :)

Comment: If you answered your own question, please do so - explain the problem and solution so others can benefit.

Comment: Sorry I meant when I visit the image in a new tab, it generates just fine. still doesn't work as part of the code though ;(

Comment: I just noticed the attribute I have written is "source" in the img tag but it needs to be "src". Whaaaaat a dummy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed the attribute I have written is "source" in the img tag but it needs to be "src". Whaaaaat a dummy. changed that and it works, of course.